# Trouble with a sed regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to handle a file containing currencies with sed but can't figure out where my error is.

This is a extract from the file :

> AED: United Arab Emirates DirhamAFN: Afghan Afghani*ALL: Albanian LekAMD: Armenian DramANG: Netherlands Antillean GuldenAOA: Angolan Kwanza*ARS: Argentine Peso*AUD: Australian DollarAWG: Aruban FlorinAZN: Azerbaijani ManatBAM: Bosnia & Herzegovina Convertible MarkBBD: Barbadian DollarBDT: Bangladeshi TakaBGN: Bulgarian LevBIF: Burundian FrancBMD: Bermudian DollarBND: Brunei DollarBOB: Bolivian Boliviano*BRL: Brazilian Real*BSD: Bahamian DollarBWP: Botswana PulaBZD: Belize DollarCAD: Canadian Dollar[...]

I want to add a newline before each tree uppercase group followed by the character ":".
What I tried was `sed -e 's/\([A-Z]{3}:)/\n\1/g list1.txt > list2.txt`, but nothing is changed. In fact, when I just try `/[A-Z]{3}/blabla/` nothing happens.

I am puzzled.

Comment: you need to escape the `{}`, also you are missing the closing paren and closing quote in the first example. It should look like `sed 's/\([A-Z]\{3\}:\)/\n\1/g'`. Also the -e is pointless.

Comment: The missing parenthesis was a typo, which I fixed in case someone reads this later. I did not know about the curly brackets nor the -e option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/([A-Z]{3}:)/\n\1/g' list1.txt
# or
# sed -e 's/\([A-Z]\{3\}:\)/\n\1/g' list1.txt
```

return:

```
AED: United Arab Emirates Dirham
AFN: Afghan Afghani
ALL: Albanian Lek
AMD: Armenian Dram
ANG: Netherlands Antillean Gulden
AOA: Angolan Kwanza
ARS: Argentine Peso
AUD: Australian Dollar
AWG: Aruban Florin
AZN: Azerbaijani Manat
BAM: Bosnia & Herzegovina Convertible Mark
BBD: Barbadian Dollar
BDT: Bangladeshi Taka
BGN: Bulgarian Lev
BIF: Burundian Franc
BMD: Bermudian Dollar
BND: Brunei Dollar
BOB: Bolivian Boliviano
BRL: Brazilian Real*
BSD: Bahamian Dollar
BWP: Botswana Pula
BZD: Belize Dollar
CAD: Canadian Dollar
```

Comment: What was my mistake? Not using the -r option? Escaping the parentheses?

Comment: @Raphaël Gomès: I posted both versions. The one using `-r` (`--regexp-extended`) is bound to GNU sed. The second one is more portable.

Comment: So, partially escaping!
Thank you very much, that was a simple problem.